# TextWatcher "onTextChanged" method issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

The count parameter in onTextChanged method of TextWatcher behaves different based on whether the `android:inputType` property is set for an edittext.

If the input type is set, it gives me the count of new character entered rather than the total characters in the edittext, if the input type is not set then it gives me the total count of characters in the edittext.

Is it a bug or Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The count in onTextChanged method gives the count of the new characters entered.So the behavior with `android:inputType` set is correct.
In order to get the total characters length use `s.length()` inside the onTextChanged method.
The strange behavior of count giving the length of total characters in edit text may be cause due to some full selection/suggestion of the edit text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question is not HOW but WHY? why two different behaviour for the same method based on "input type" property is set or not for an edittext.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded an example you can even download it([link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7yit56o8s7yniyh/textwatcher.rar)).In editText user can enter maximum 10 characters.As the user enter/removes characters total length will be output in textview.

```
 android:inputType set is correct. In order to get the total characters length use           s.length() inside the onTextChanged method
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question is not HOW but WHY? why two different behaviour for the same method based on "input type" property is set or not for an edittext